# Sidebar slideshow widget

Tags: images

Anyone know any quality image slideshow widgets that can be put on a sidebar?

Answer (score 3):

If your just going to be showing images [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) is the way to go.  It is very light and you simply call the js in your theme then wrap your images in a div ie:

```
<div class="pics"> 
    <img src="images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
    <img src="images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
    <img src="images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
</div>
```

Then add the call in your footer ie:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
;( function( $ ) {
    $('.pics').cycle('fade');
} )( jQuery );
</script>
```

If your looking for a simple slider that calls posts by category and can be embedded in a post, page, or widget using shortcodes check out my [WP Coda Slider Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-coda-slider/) that I recently released.

Answer (score 2):

I built a very basic image rotator for a client once.  It pulls a random sampling (with a configurable maximum number) of images from available attachments in the WordPress database and resizes them for display in the sidebar.  The advantage of server-side resizing is a faster page load (though images larger than 2MB will get stuck in the system and won't load properly).

It's called Rotating Image Widget and is hosted in the [WordPress plug-in repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rotating-image-widget/) (meaning it's free and open source).  If you make any changes to the code, please let me know so I can incorporate your improvements into the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I use http://www.slidedeck.com/ its free for the basic version, the advanced (payfor) give you vertical scrolling as well as horizonal (more iPad'eske). I took about 5 minutes to setup and comes with a couple of nice looking templates. The control panel in \wp-admin is really easy to use and can link to your forum posts. Good luck!